# Height issues in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've got a report that needs to print as landscape letter size.  This report uses a detailed header for the 1st page, and a more concise header for every other page.  The problem I'm running into is that having both headers defined in iReport has made the report too large to fit the letter size constraints (in terms of height).

When I print the report, the correct headers display on their correct pages, but the report is too large and contains massive amounts of whitespace.  The printer then tries to center the report and ends up clipping portions of the header and footer so I only get the midsection of the report.

Is there some way to configure my report to have 2 versions of 1 report band (in this case the pageHeader band) and then just provide an expression to determine when each version should print?  Or can I group bands together somehow so that iReport knows they occupy the same space?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't ever find any sort of fancy way of doing this, so I just made the 2 headers into subreports and included both in the same location on the pageHeader band.  Problem solved.

Comment: I had the same problem and did pretty much the exact same thing.